# Laravel if statement with other variable value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I try to get data from a model, but the value of the column name from the data model is in another variable. Here's a little preview what I try to achieve:

```
switch($device->target_objectclass_id) {
    case 10:
        $handler = Servers::findOrFail($device->target_object_id);
    default:
        break;
}

if($handler->($condition->column) ($condition->condition) ($condition->value)) {
    //process the other data it it's true
}
```

Example of what should be displayed:

```
if($handler->status == 1) { 
    //handle data 
}
```

The reason behide this is a little bit complicated. The user's need to create `triggers` which will be executed.

Btw, all possible conditons are possible.

---

For example:

- check table where `column` `condition` `value`
- check servers where status == 1

Hope someone has an answer if you can understand my problem...

Comment: Do you have many operators/conditions, such as `==`, if it's a limited number, then this might be possible. It's the operator that presents the biggest issue.

Comment: @Jonathon all possible operators/conditions you can imagen are possible.

Comment: Oh right, well that makes it more difficult then. I don't know if there's a way to dynamically program in an operator into an expression. However, take a look at my answer below. If you are able to implement all the operators you can think to use, then you could do what I have done below. This would also give you the flexibility to define your own operators too.

Comment: Sounds better suited to events and listeners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how feasible it is to dynamically insert the operator into an expression like that. However, with a limited set of operators, you could do something like this:

```
class YourClass
{
    public function yourMethod()
    {
        // Your model instance to test, I've just used a stdClass as an example
        $instance = new stdClass;
        $instance->status = 1;

        // Your condition instance
        $condition = new stdClass;
        $condition->column = 'status';
        $condition->condition = '==';
        $condition->value = '1';

        if ($this->compare($instance, $condition)) {
            // This code will execute then $instance->status == '1'
        }
    }

    public function compare($instance, $condition)
    {
        $operator = $condition->condition;
        $condition = $condition->column;
        $value = $condition->value;

        switch ($operator) {
            case '==':
                return $instance->$column == $value;
            case '!=':
                return $instance->$column != $value;
            case '>':
                return $instance->$column > $value;
            case '<':
                return $instance->$column < $value;
            case '>=':
                return $instance->$column >= $value;
            case '<=':
                return $instance->$column <= $value;
            default:
                throw new \Exception('Unsupported operator');
        }
    }
}
```

Or a nicer, class based way of doing it...

```
class Conditional
{
    protected $operator;
    protected $column;
    protected $value;
    protected $supportedOperators = [
        '==' => 'equals',
        '!=' => 'notEquals'
    ];

    public function __construct($column, $operator, $value)
    {
        $this->column = $column;
        $this->operator = $operator;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    public function check($instance)
    {
        $method = $this->getMethod();

        $instanceValue = $instance->{$this->column};

        return $this->$method($instanceValue, $this->value);
    }

    private function getMethod()
    {
        if (isset($this->supportedOperators[$this->operator]) && method_exists($this, $this->supportedOperators[$this->operator])) {
            return $this->supportedOperators[$this->operator];
        }

        throw new \Exception('Unsupported operator');
    }

    protected function equals($one, $two)
    {
        return $one == $two;
    }

    protected function notEquals($one, $two)
    {
        return $one != $two;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this...

```
$instance = new stdClass;
$instance->status = 1;

$conditional = new Conditional('status', '==', 1);
if ($conditional->check($instance)) {
    // Execute if $instance->status == 1.
}
```